# I have two onchange methods and two values I need to pass

Tags: javascript, html

```
function changeHiddenInput(cLeague, nLeague) {
        console.log(cLeague);
        console.log(nLeague);
        var objHidden1 = document.getElementById("hiddenInput1");
        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("hiddenInput2");
        objHidden1.value = cLeague.value;
        objHidden2.value = nLeague.value;
        var a = objHidden1.value;
        var b = objHidden1.value;
        result.innerHTML = a + b;
    }

<select class="form-control" id="currentleague" onchange="document.getElementById('currentleague').src=this.value; changeHiddenInput(select)">
    <option value="rankicons/bronze5.png" (another value goes somewhere in here)>Bronze V</option>
</select>
```

Basically the first onchange changes the image in value, the second onchange passes in a value and does some math. Is there an alternative I could use to value or could I somehow pass in two values and somehow tell them apart?

Comment: unclear question! and what does this mean? `<option value="rankicons/bronze5.png" (another value goes somewhere in here)>Bronze V</option>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 2 values within the value property:

```
<option value="rankicons/bronze5.png,value nr 2">...</option>
```

Sample:

```
function changeHiddenInput(league) {
        var league_values = league.split(",");
        var objHidden1 = document.getElementById("hiddenInput1");
        var objHidden2 = document.getElementById("hiddenInput2");
        objHidden1.value = league_values[0];
        objHidden2.value = league_values[1];
        var a = objHidden1.value;
        var b = objHidden1.value;
        result.innerHTML = a + b;
        // remove comment and set uniqe id to set img element src
        //document.getElementById('img_id').src=league_values[0];
    }
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="currentleague" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="rankicons/bronze5.png,value nr 2">...</option>
</select>
```

The value `document.getElementById('currentleague').src=this.value;` I removed as it referenced the select element itself (same id) and added it to your function instead.